# Проблема с созданием pdf файла из сконвертированного в exe проекта python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. В проекте создаю pdf файлы. В главном модуле (main.py) есть функция (def otchet_kassira), которая собирает исходные данные и запускает другую функцию (def otchet_kassira), создающую pdf.

```
def otchet_kassira(self):
    """Формирование отчета кассира"""
    logger.info("Inside the function def otchet_kassira")
    path = "./otchet.pdf"
    path = os.path.realpath(path)
    """Удаляем предыдущий файл"""
    row_tab_1 = self.ui.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
    row_tab_2 = self.ui.tableWidget_4.rowCount()
    if row_tab_1 >= 1 and row_tab_2 >= 1:
        os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM SumatraPDF.exe")
        if os.path.exists(path):
            os.remove(path)
        dt1 = self.ui.dateEdit_2.date().toString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        dt2 = self.ui.dateEdit.date().toString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        # формируем данные
        logger.info(self.ui.tableWidget_3.item(0, 0).text())
        logger.info(System.pc_name)
        if System.pc_name == self.ui.tableWidget_4.item(0, 0).text():
            values = [self.ui.tableWidget_4.item(0, 1).text(),
                      self.ui.tableWidget_4.item(0, 2).text()]
        else:
            values = [self.ui.tableWidget_4.item(1, 1).text(),
                      self.ui.tableWidget_4.item(1, 2).text()]
        logger.info(values)
        otchet.otchet_kassira(values, dt1, dt2, System.user)
        os.startfile(path)

def otchet_kassira(val, date1, date2, kassir):
"""Формирование отчета кассира"""
path = "./otchet.pdf"
values, dt1, dt2, user = val, date1, date2, kassir
print('values', values)
c = canvas.Canvas(path, pagesize=A4)
c.setLineWidth(.3)
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('DejaVuSerif', 'files/DejaVuSerif.ttf'))
c.setFont('DejaVuSerif', 12)
c.drawString(30, 800, 'Организация')
c.drawString(30, 785, 'АО "Рога и копыта"')
c.drawString(450, 800, "Приложение №1")
c.drawString(255, 685, 'Отчет кассира')
c.drawString(255, 670, 'по оказанным услугам')
if dt1 == dt2:
    c.drawString(255, 655, f"за {dt1}")
else:
    c.drawString(255, 655, f"за {dt1} - {dt2}")
# рисуем линию
c.setLineWidth(1)
c.line(275, 652, 430, 652)
# ФИО персонала
c.drawString(255, 623, f"{user[0]} {user[1]}")
c.setLineWidth(1)
c.line(100, 621, 500, 621)
c.setFont('DejaVuSerif', 8)
c.drawString(255, 610, 'ФИО кассира')
data = [['№ п/п', 'Тип\nпродажи', 'Сумма, руб.'],
        ['1', 'Банковская карта', values[0]],
        ['2', 'Наличные', values[1]],
        ['3', 'Итого', int(values[0]) + int(values[1])]]
t = Table(data, 4 * [1.2 * inch], 4 * [0.3 * inch])
t.setStyle(TableStyle([('FONT', (0, 0), (4, 4), 'DejaVuSerif', 8),
                       ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.2, colors.black),
                       ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.2, colors.black)]))
# wrap the table to this width, height in case it spills
t.wrapOn(c, 100 * mm, 180 * mm)
# draw it on our pdf at x,y
t.drawOn(c, 20 * mm, 170 * mm)
# отчет сдал
c.drawString(30, 310, 'Отчет сдал:')
c.drawString(30, 290, 'Кассир')
c.setLineWidth(1)
c.line(150, 290, 240, 290)
c.setFont('DejaVuSerif', 8)
c.drawString(165, 282, 'Подпись')
c.line(300, 290, 390, 290)
c.setFont('DejaVuSerif', 8)
c.drawString(315, 282, 'Расшифровка')
# отчет принял
c.drawString(30, 210, 'Отчет принял:')
c.drawString(30, 190, 'Старший администратор')
c.setLineWidth(1)
c.line(150, 190, 240, 190)
c.setFont('DejaVuSerif', 8)
c.drawString(175, 182, 'Подпись')
c.line(300, 190, 390, 190)
c.setFont('DejaVuSerif', 8)
c.drawString(325, 182, 'Расшифровка')
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Из отдельного .py файла otchet.pdf создается. Если сконвертировать .py в exe, то тоже все в порядке. Удаление файла (os.remove(path)) происходит корректно. Если закомментировать удаление отчета и запустить готовый файл otchet.pdf командой os.startfile(path), то он открывается корректно. Не пойму в чем может быть дело.
Если же переименовать main.py в main.pyw, то все работает. Но хотелось бы оградить пользователя от файла с исходным кодом и не ставить python рабочую станцию.
Конвертирую проект в exe при помощи auto-py-to-exe (это gui к pyinstaller).
json файл с параметрами конвертации.

```
{
 "version": "auto-py-to-exe-configuration_v1",
 "pyinstallerOptions": [
  {
   "optionDest": "noconfirm",
   "value": true
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "filenames",
   "value": "C:/Project/main.py"
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "onefile",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "console",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "icon_file",
   "value": "C:/Project/files/logo.ico"
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "ascii",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "clean_build",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "strip",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "noupx",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "disable_windowed_traceback",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "embed_manifest",
   "value": true
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "uac_admin",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "uac_uiaccess",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "win_private_assemblies",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "win_no_prefer_redirects",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "bootloader_ignore_signals",
   "value": false
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "datas",
   "value": "C:/Project/files/model;model/"
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "datas",
   "value": "C:/Project/files/platforms;platforms/"
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "datas",
   "value": "C:/Project/config.ini;."
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "datas",
   "value": "C:/Project/debug.log;."
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "datas",
   "value": "C:/Project/print.cmd;."
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "datas",
   "value": "C:/Project/pylogo.png;."
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "datas",
   "value": "C:/Project/SumatraPDF.exe;."
  },
  {
   "optionDest": "datas",
   "value": "C:/Project/SumatraPDF-settings.txt;."
  }
 ],
 "nonPyinstallerOptions": {
  "increaseRecursionLimit": true,
  "manualArguments": ""
 }
}
```

Вроде бы пустяковое дело - перегнать все в exe, но не могу понять в чем дело. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что не указал в pyinstaller`e каталог с файлом otchet.py, который генерирует pdf.